# Unable to plot multiple lines in a single graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, binance

I am having a weird issue, I am trying to plot multiple lines in a single graph but it is only one. I am sharing the screenshot as you can see the close values are different in both. It is not rendering binance graph as it seems to be overridden.

[image]

**Graph**

[image]

*Update*

The code is given below

```
# All Imports
import ccxt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Connect binance
binance = ccxt.binance()
ftx = ccxt.ftx()
binance_btc_usdt_ohlcv = binance.fetch_ohlcv('BTC/USDT','1d',limit=100)
ftx_btc_usdt_ohlcv = ftx.fetch_ohlcv('BTC/USDT','1d',limit=100)
df_binance = pd.DataFrame(binance_btc_usdt_ohlcv, columns=['ts', 'o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'v'])
df_ftx = pd.DataFrame(ftx_btc_usdt_ohlcv, columns=['ts', 'o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'v'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df_binance['ts'], df_binance['v'],label='Binance')
ax.plot(df_ftx['ts'], df_ftx['v'],label='FTX')

plt.legend()
# ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `pandas 1.3.3`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`**

### Existing Code

- Works without any issues, however, `'Binance'` is small compared to `'FTX'`, which can be resolved with `ax.set_yscale('log')`

```py
df_binance = pd.DataFrame(binance_btc_usdt_ohlcv, columns=['ts', 'o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'v'])
df_ftx = pd.DataFrame(ftx_btc_usdt_ohlcv, columns=['ts', 'o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'v'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df_binance['ts'], df_binance['v'], label='Binance')
ax.plot(df_ftx['ts'], df_ftx['v'], label='FTX')

ax.legend()
ax.set_yscale('log')  # resolve issues of scale with the y-axis values
plt.show()
```

[image]

- Without `ax.set_yscale('log')`, `'Binance'` still shows up on the plot

[image]

---

- The text code example in the OP used `'v'`, but the issue was occuring with `'c'` (in the screenshot).

  - The issue is `df_ftx.c` and `df_binance.c` are almost exactly the same, which we can see by using `alpha=0.5`.

```py
# plot dataframe
ax = df_binance.plot(x='ts', y='c', label='Binance', figsize=(8, 6), logy=True)
p2 = df_ftx.plot(x='ts', y='c', label='FTX', ax=ax, alpha=0.5)

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

- Given the scale of the y-axis, the difference is too small to differentiate the two lines.

```py
>>> df_binance.c.sub(df_ftx.c)

0      1.00
1     -2.13
2      0.07
3     -2.44
4     -0.35
5      1.35
6     11.51
7     -6.17
8    -11.91
9     -2.86
10   -13.98
11    -7.40
12    -3.13
13     1.56
14   -15.52
15    -8.63
16     0.83
17    10.44
18     0.82
19    -0.95
20   -12.82
21    -2.54
22   -15.13
23   -14.46
24    -4.63
25   -12.60
26   -10.01
27   -17.00
28    -4.00
29   -16.00
30    -9.49
31    -5.18
32    -3.71
33    23.95
34    -4.71
35    -2.38
36   -11.53
37    -7.13
38   -10.78
39     1.85
40     0.01
41    -9.68
42     7.87
43     9.90
44    -4.65
45     2.83
46     5.91
47    -3.11
48   -14.48
49   -11.36
50    -0.86
51     2.64
52   -22.12
53    -8.10
54    -6.27
55    -3.69
56    -0.86
57     1.91
58     5.69
59     1.24
60    -1.27
61   -12.48
62    -1.59
63    -8.18
64     5.98
65    -6.26
66    -4.25
67    -2.38
68    11.38
69    -9.39
70    -4.74
71    -0.43
72    -9.36
73    -3.10
74    -0.65
75     1.54
76    -2.72
77    -1.90
78    -0.39
79    -9.10
80    -4.99
81    -6.06
82     6.99
83     0.00
84    -8.78
85     2.43
86    -2.28
87   -10.00
88    -9.65
89    -5.07
90    -1.00
91    -0.06
92   -28.58
93    -8.43
94    -8.67
95   -17.16
96    -3.41
97   -12.59
98    -1.85
99     5.99
Name: c, dtype: float64
```

---

### Updated Code

- Convert `'ts'` to a `datetime dtype` with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)
- Plot directly with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) since the data is in a dataframe

  - This example plots to a `secondary_y`, otherwise use the parameter `logy=True`.

```py
df_binance = pd.DataFrame(binance_btc_usdt_ohlcv, columns=['ts', 'o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'v'])
df_binance.ts = pd.to_datetime(df_binance.ts, unit='ms')  # convert column to a datetime dtype

df_ftx = pd.DataFrame(ftx_btc_usdt_ohlcv, columns=['ts', 'o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'v'])
df_ftx.ts = pd.to_datetime(df_ftx.ts, unit='ms')  # convert column to a datetime dtype

# plot dataframe
ax = df_binance.plot(x='ts', y='v', label='Binance', figsize=(8, 6))
p2 = df_ftx.plot(x='ts', y='v', label='FTX', ax=ax, secondary_y=True)

ax.legend(loc='upper left')
p2.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

- Using `logy=True` instead of `secondary_y=True`

```py
# plot dataframe
ax = df_binance.plot(x='ts', y='v', label='Binance', figsize=(8, 6), logy=True)
p2 = df_ftx.plot(x='ts', y='v', label='FTX', ax=ax)

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I will try it so it is all due to a scaling issue? _Close_ value looks very similar so do not know why is scaling the issue.

Comment: @Volatil3 with your existing code, Binance shows up even if I don't scale the yaxis. So I don't really know why it's not displaying in your plot. I'm also testing it in jupyter. Just make sure you're using the current version of matplotlib and pandas. If you're using conda, go to the anaconda prompt, activate the environment (if you're using something other than `base`), and do `conda update --all`

Comment: @Volatil3 the issue is `df_ftx.c` and `df_binance.c` are almost exactly the same. Note the update to the answer.

Comment: I installed the updated version of both via `pip` and both are the latest versions: 3.3.4 and 1.3.1. Do not know where I am doing wrong. However I do find inconsistency in my conda environment.

Comment: @Volatil3 Note that the issue is because the values in column `c` of both dataframes are almost the same, so the lines overlap

Comment: so how can I make Matplotlib plot these subtle differences?